# Android Moshi Json Converter Causes kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KotlinReflectionInternalError

Tags: android, retrofit, moshi, android-r8

I am using Moshi as Json Converter with Retrofit in Android.

When I set minifyEnabled to true, For some API calls it works, but for others it throws this Error:

This callable does not support a default call: public constructor ErrorResponse.

Note that I am using a custom NetworkResponseAdapter and NetworkResponseCall. The exception is thrown on this line in the NetworkResponseCall when I try to convert the Json response to the ErrorResponse Data class: errorConverter.convert(error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update!!**
**The Solution:**

It turned out I need to add the CodeGen Kapt or KSP dependency **com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.15.0** in addition to **@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)** for the Classes that use Moshi.

Details **[here](https://github.com/square/moshi)**

Answer (score 0):

When you enable the minify option, the compiler replaces your class names, fields and so on. Instead of `MyAdapter` class, `execute` method and `name` inside model that is serialized by Moshi, they will become `Abc` class, `adcd` method and `gr` for field. Thies includes internal information that requires for reflection and generics.

In order to fix this, you must write set of rules in `proguard-rules.pro` file by default to exclude peaces of code from renaming and other operations. In practice, every popular library adds such rules itself. However with custom classes as your adapter or serialized data classes, you need to add rules manually.

[Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/build/shrink-code#keep-code), [Short Guide](https://blog.logrocket.com/r8-code-shrinking-android-guide/), [ProGuard Manual](https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/configuration/usage)

Comment: I have already added a rule to keep the Custom Network Adapter Factory and Network Call classes. Can you please clarify more regarding my case.

Comment: @OmarAssidi you wrote `convert the Json response to the ErrorResponse Data class`. I suppose additional to the custom adapter, you need to add `ErrorResponse` and other data classes to proguard rules in order to exclude them from obfuscation.  Because when Moshi tries to convert json string to model it can not find keys from string in your model.

Comment: I see what you mean, I have already tried to keep the data classes using this -keep class com.example.yourpackage.** { *; }, but the issue seems to persist.